# How many particular solutions to a second order linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have the differential equation
$$y''-y'-2y=3x+2,$$
I can make the guess that a particular solution is of the form
$$y = Ax+B,$$
and determine the coefficients. Do I always have exactly one particular solution (which can be comprised of different additive terms depending on the function on the right side of the differential equation) or can I have more than one particular solution?

Comment: You need two independant solutions for the general solution of the homogeneous ODE. Then, you need to add only one particular solution (any one) of the non-homogeneous ODE in order to obtain it's general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y=A(x)$ and $y=B(x)$ are solutions of $y''-y'-2y=3x+2$, then you can check that $y=A(x)-B(x)$ is a solution of $y''-y'-2y=0$, which is the related homogeneous equation.

So any two different particular solutions differ by a solution of the related homogeneous equation. So you may as well find the simplest solution you can.